# REST API not returning expected results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to follow the article [Build RESTful API's with ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) to learn how to create a RESTful API.

I created the first project and controller, `Contact`.

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    // GET: Contact
    public string[] Index()
    {
        return new string[]
        {
            "Hello",
            "World"
        };
    }
}
```

But when I load the URL in a browser, instead of getting the response described in the article (`["Hello","World"]`). The response I get is `System.String[]`.

I don't understand what I'm missing.

BTW, the article is from 2013. Does anyone know of a good article that is perhaps a little newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have now is simple ASP.NET MVC controller. For Web API controller you should inherit your controller from `ApiController` instead of `Controller`:

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
```

Also action names should start with HTTP verb. If you'll send GET request to `/api/contact` endpoint you'll get error

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

By default action name is not used in route for Web API controllers. If you'll check default route configuration, it will be `api/{controller}/id`. Correct action is selected via HTTP method of request. In your case it should be `GetXXX` or simply `Get`

Comment: Well, yes, that appears to be the situation. Wonder why such a POS article. It doesn't mention `ApiController` or `Get` until one of the later examples!

Comment: @JonathanWood yep, I wonder why author didn't point on correct class. There is just mention on screenshot - scaffolding template for adding new controller is *Empty API controller*

Comment: Can I ask another question? Looks like it's returning JSON. Can this be configured?

Comment: @JonathanWood yep again. It's called *content negotiation*. You should pass `Accept` header with your request. E.g. `Accept: application/xml` for xml

Comment: I was understanding that REST APIs are called using a regular URL. So how do you attach a header just using a URL? Also, what if I just want to return the data in a format like CSV? Is that possible?

Comment: @JonathanWood by default there is only two response formatters - json and xml. But you can add any formatters you like pdf, png or csv. See [Download CSV using ASP.NET Web API](http://www.vickram.me/download-csv-using-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Return regular primitives from the Web Apis. At least if not if you are using a regular MVC Web API from .net. So, if this is the case you could do something like

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    // GET: Contact
    public JsonResult Index()
    {   
        return Json(new { value1: "Hello", value2: "world" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the technique being used in the article.